# Integration Akka with Spring and OSGI (No configuration setting found for key 'akka')

Tags: spring, configuration, osgi, classloader, akka

I'v added one `Akka` actor to my app that works with `Spring` and `OSGI`.

I try to use Actor from `Spring @Component bean` like this:

```
private final ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("actor-system");
private ActorRef managerActorRef = system.actorOf(Props.create(ManagerActor.class), "ldapManagerActor");
```

When I start the app it throws an exception (`No configuration setting found for key 'akka'`):

```
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.
beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.myconpany....ByBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka'
```

I've look at [this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/general/configuration.html#A_Word_About_ClassLoaders): doc. And seems the root of my problem is related to `class loader` that I should pass to/for `akka-system` and `application.conf` file that describes this.

But I could not find appropriate `stets` to make it all working so far.

**Could someone help?**

---

**My tries:**

Flowing [this](http://www.caffeinatedideas.com/2013/02/autowiring-akka-actors-with-spring/) article.

When I put:

```
<bean id="actorSystem" class="akka.actor.ActorSystem" factory-method="create" scope="singleton"></bean>
```

I have the similar error:

```
Could not autowire field: private akka.actor.ActorSystem

com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting fou
nd for key 'akka'
```

Comment: Do you have an application.conf file and if so, can you post it as well as let me know if that file is available at the root of the classpath.

Comment: already have. I've just put there all that akka-actor_.jar/referece.conf has. And it seems it starts working. Will check soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use Akka actors you don't need to pass in application.conf settings. You can just use the default. Make sure you have the config library on your class path.

You didn't mention what version of Akka youre using, however if you grab the latest Akka 2.2 RC you can use an IndirectActorProducer to handle the spring wiring.

See this article on how to do that; http://blog.nemccarthy.me/?p=272

You should also tell Spring to call shutdown on the ActorSystem to cleanly shutdown. There is also an updated guide on how to integrate the ActorSystem into Spring or a web app [here](http://blog.nemccarthy.me/?p=295)